# Error running and deploying 'People' from NetGuru Rails 4.0.3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, deployment

I am trying to run https://github.com/netguru/people but keep getting issues. When I push it to heroku i get errors, when I copied the files to my projects folder and run 'rails server' I get  rails server
Your Ruby version is 2.1.1, but your Gemfile specified 2.0.0

I updated the ruby version in gem file but still run into issues.

Any help would be appreciated. Running Mac OSX Mavericks

Answer (score 1):

I believe you've got your answer here https://github.com/netguru/people/issues/3

> try to do:
>
> `gem install bundler rails`
>
> and then just do
>
> `bundle`